# Generating a random sample of integers with unequal probability in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I am trying to use the Rcpp `sample` function, but I want to sample without replacement and with unequal probability. However I am struggling to understand what form the argument `sugar::probs_t probs` should take, because I cannot find the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sugar::probs_t` is a typedef of `Nullable< Vector<REALSXP> >` (see the [`inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sample.h`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/4e50e2bc4405309d3519575ff6cf8e7c57729b3d/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sample.h#L395) code file). So, if you pass it a `Rcpp::NumericVector`, then everything should be fine.

As you didn't provide any example code, lets look at an implementation in the [unit test file for sugar](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/e81493bd988a5ee93e5a35458662dd2582de1c5d/inst/unitTests/cpp/sugar.cpp#L1148-L1190):

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector sample_dbl(NumericVector x, int sz, bool rep = false, sugar::probs_t p = R_NilValue)
{
    return sample(x, sz, rep, p);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @coatless . I did search the implementation for the definition but missed it somehow.